# Ignore SSL Validation In Eclipse Ivy IvyDE plugin

Tags: eclipse, ssl, ivy, ivyde

Recently our compare have installed ForcePoint (once called WebSense) that, as was explained to me, intercepts certifates from SSL sites and 'does something with them' in that it changes the originating host within the certifcate.

This has had an effect on my Eclipse IDE where I have several plugins, namely Git & Ivy plugins, that access HTTPS sites. These all started failing after this network update, with errors such as 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'

I've managed to overcome this for Git by specifying sslVerify=false.
But I cannot seem to find the equivalent or a similar setting for the Ivy plug IvyDE.

I've tried adding the certificate the Java TrustStore, and also creating another TrustStore and explicitly passing this into Eclipse via eclipse.ini. I would have thought that there would be a similar option for Ivy to ignore SSL verification as there is for Git.